# Where to Buy Symantec Storage Foundation for Windows (Nee Veritas)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

We are interested in licensing Symantec Storage Foundation for Windows (used to be Veritas).  This should be an exceptionally easy task, but it is proving to be monumentally difficult.

So far, we have:

1.)  Chatted (by text) with Symantec, only to get passed off to CDW

2.)  Chatted with CDW accout rep, they can't figure out how to license it to us

3.)  Called a different CDW account rep who said they would call Symantec and get back us "in a day or two"

4.)  Had CDW rep call us back and tell us they could not sell it to us or get a price because Symantec would not give them the needed info.

5.)  Called Symantec Business Sales.  They could not sell it to us either.  Nor could they give us a price.  The best they could do is "have someone call us back" in two to three business days.

So, I know how one might *at first* think that this should be super straightforward, but more than a week and a half has passed an no one has called us back and I can't figure out how to license the damn thing.

Does anyone out there (a) know someone to contact that actually knows something about Storage Foundation for Windows or (b) know that the product is dead or in the process of getting sold or some such?

Any ideas!!??

Comment: I'd be very wary of purchasing a product that the vendor isn't able to sell. If they can't manage to get it together to sell it, how likely are they to be able to be able to support it properly.

Comment: I know what you mean!  Officially, they sell it through resellers (VARs).  Its just that they don't have a list of VARS who *know* anything about it.  They all can see this huge price sheet of SKU's but they don't know which is which etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Symantec Partner Locator](http://partnerlocator.symantec.com/public/search/) to find someone near you. Or better still, find a few, then contact them and tell them your requirements. Then decide who serves you best. If you can get a decent partner, then it also makes your life easier when the support is up for renewal, or if you need to buy additional licenses.

For Storage Foundation you can't buy it off the self, and you can't buy it from Symantec. Contacting Symantec will lead to them passing your details on to one of their partners, and some of them may not be very good at contacting you, from experience!

I hope that SFW isn't dying, as I use it! It hasn't had many updates recently, but if it keeps doing the job you need, and you keep renewing the support contract, there's no reason for Symantec to release an update.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when things like this are terribly hard to purchase, it means that all the sales reps are worried about commissions and metrics. If they're usually selling $100k orders, and your order is a measly $1k, it drops their average sale down by a lot - usually costing them more in compensation than your sale costs you. I've found this to be the case with several large companies, including the one who probably makes the fob on your keyring that generates 6 new digits every minute.